# Iterate through a list of words and search through a folder to find file(s) containing that word

Tags: c#, loops

Lets say I have a text file MyFile.txt with following content:

```
hellosam
whatsup
mynameisjohn
etc...
```

I want to go through each word in MyFile.txt and then see which file in my local
folder C:\myfolders\myallfiles contain that word.

For example, I want to see which file would contain reference to hellosam and so on so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably something similiar to this... this is more psuedo-code. Its more fun to figure the rest out yourself.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("directorypath");

    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(s);
        StreamReader reader = file.OpenText();

        if(reader.ReadToEnd().Contains("string you are looking for"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```